# "The specified network name is no longer available" after little time inactivity

Tags: networking, windows-10

From a Windows 10 machine I use to connect to a remote machine.
While some activity is performed between the two machines, everything is OK, but, if I stop all communications among them for a while (e. g. 5 minutes), the first subsequent attempt to connect the remote machine fails with error "The specified network name is no longer available". Attempting one more connection succeeds.
It looks like something goes to sleep, and takes a bit to wake up.
It also seems like the problem arises ONLY when connecting from my machine, while any attempt to connect to the same machine from other computers is OK.

Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Note: I saw many other questions that report the same error, but the cause seems different. RoboCopy is not involved, nor any antivirus (Norton or Symantec)

Answer (score 0):

as workaround, You can try to force recreate connection by simple command `dir` , eg. to force reconnect network share drive `x:`, put command in shortcut like:

```
dir x: >nul
```